# How to display a splash screen using Caliburn Micro

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn Micro v1.3 with WPF. I would like to display a splash screen while my app loads.

I have overriden OnStartup as below but can't see how to close my splash when the base.OnStartup complete

```
    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var wm = new WindowManager();
        var vm = new StatusReporterViewModel("TEST", "information", null);

        try
        {
            wm.ShowWindow(vm);

            base.OnStartup(sender, e);

        }
        finally            
        {
            vm.TryClose();
        }

    }
```

Any ideas?

Cheers

Steve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use the default WPF splash mechanism then it requires no code.

Add an image file to your WPF .EXE project and then set the properties on the image to "SplashScreen"

[image]

Comment: Looked like a good solution but did not work. I get a cannot locate resource error. Probably Caliburn causing this.

Answer (score 1):

If your Splash Screen is an actual customized Window, you can close the SplashScreen in the *OnInitialize()* Method of your ShellViewModel (or if you dont have a shell, the first view model that gets activated). To get a reference to the SplashScreen in your Shell either inject it or make it a singleton